# Sliding window of entire length of the file

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a tab delimited file which contains about 2207 rows with 4 columns of `float`s or `int` types:

> ```
> Id    pos    value1    value2
> 01    1123   0.76483   0.9001
> 02    1124   0.20      0.9800
> ```

Another file is to be compared with which contains about 27041 rows with also 4 columns:

> ```
> name    Id    pos1    pos2
> s13e    01    234     800
> zz12    01    800     866
> ```

Now, my goal is to find **all possible consecutive rows of 3 or higher** in which:

1. Their contents of the first column of the first file (Id) are equal to the second column of the second file (Id).
2. Their contents of the second column of the first file (pos) is in between the range of column 3 and column 4 of the second file.

My approach is to do the following:

1. Loop through a sliding window of length 3 to the entire length number of rows of the first file (that's my outer loop)
2. Second loop is to iterate and take each element of the sliding window of some specific length like 3 for instance and then
3. Check if that element satisfy the conditions above if it is satisfy then break the loop to take the next element of the first file
4. Otherwise, continue searching for the second file to find the target

For a length 300 rows of the first file the whole sliding window thing with the checking to the second file takes about 5 minutes. However, I am looking for a faster and more efficient way to do that.

An example of a satisfied result is the following:

let's say we have performed a window sliding of a length 3, **Note that I have to iterate over the entire length of the file (number of rows) and the length of 3 for the sliding window is just an example!**

From file 1:

> ```
> idW = (01,01,01)
> posW = (127, 192,199)
> val1W = (.9,.01,.23)
> val2W = (.2,.03,.43)
> ```

From file 2:

> ```
> name    Id    pos1    pos2
> s13e    01    120     200
> ```

For a successful result, the following will have to be met:

- Consecutive rows of 3 rows **and** (true)
- Id of file1 are equal file2 **and** (true)
- `posW` from the first file are in between the values of `pos1` and `pos2` (true)

The result is satisfy because all conditions above are true and met.

This code is working fine but I want it to be the fastest possible and more efficient:

```py
# borrowed from one answer from stack overflow 
def sliding_window (s, n):
 it = iter(seq)
 result = tuple(islice(it, n))
 if len(result) == n:
    yield result
 for elem in it:
    result = result[1:] + (elem,)
    yield result

Ids, pos, val1, val2 = zip(*Data)
# len_Data is the entire length of the file 
for windwCounts in range(3,len_Data):
    file2count = 0
    swindow_id = sliding_window(Ids, windwCounts)
    swindow_pos = sliding_window(pos, windwCounts)
    swindow_val1 = sliding_window(val1, windwCounts)
    swindow_val2 = sliding_window(val2, windwCounts)
    slidingWindws = zip(swindow_id, swindow_pos,
                        swindow_val1, swindow_val2)
    for idW, posW, val1W, val2W in slidingWindws:
     while (file2count <= len_file2):
            name,id2,pos1,pos2 = file2[file2count]
            # No point of moving down if the pos of file1 is less than pos2 of file2
            if any(int(ps) < pos2 for ps in posW):
                    break
            # All conditions must be met:-
            ids_cond = all(a_id == id2 for a_id in idW)
            within_data = all(pos1 <= int(ps) <= pos2
                                       for ps in posW)
            if ids_cond and within_data:

                  print "satisfy"
                  break 

            else:
                  print "not satisfy"
            file2count += 1
```

Comment: I encountered your post when looking for old, unanswered question. It appears your question is incomplete. The imports are missing and you're not opening any files here. I'm perfectly willing to analyse your code to dust, but I'll need something complete to run to verify whether my improvements are actually faster than your approach. If you're willing to add that information, that would be great. You may be interested in reading our [FAQ on getting the most out of Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915).